# Get total number of orders per month and the total quantity ordered per month in django ORM

Tags: django

I have the following two models:

```
 class Order(models.Model):
     set_on = models.DateField()

 class Details(models.Model):
     order = models.ForgienKey(Order, related_name='order_detail')
     quantity = models.IntegerField()
     item = models.CharField()
```

And the data now is:

```
id       set_on
1        2017-07-01
2        2017-07-10
3        2017-08-01
4        2017-09-01
```

and details:

```
id  order_id  quantity  item
1   1         10        box
2   1         11        pens
3   3          5        box
```

The desired output is now:

```
period       total orders     total quantity
07/2017      2                21 
08/2017      1                5
09/2017      1                0
```

In 07/2017, 2 orders were made with a total quantity of 21.

This is what I have so far. It brings quantities Ok but total orders made is always equal to the highest. i.e. 2 in the above even for months 8 and 9 when the total number of orders started were 1 only.

```
data = Order.objects.all().annotate(mon=Extract('set_on','month'), yr=Extract('set_on','year')).values('mon', 'yr').annotate(total_orders=Count('mon','yr'), total_quantity=Sum('order_detail__quantity'))
```

How can I fix it to get the desired output?

Comment: Have you tried total_orders=Count('id')

Comment: Yes I did and it doesnt work cos it groups on orders.id, which doesn't sum up quantities